# Multivariate Poisson loss function in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to perform a multivariate Poisson regression with Keras. In other words, I want to maximise `Product[P(y_true[i] | y_pred[i])]` for each element in the output vector (`i`). In this case, P will the the Poisson pmf.

I believe that I can do this with a custom loss function. However, working out how to implement this loss function using the available functions in `keras.backend` is proving to be a challenge.

In particular, I am unable to find a way to implement elementwise factorial on a 1D tensor, something required to calculate the Poisson pmf.

Does anyone have any pointers for how this might be done? Or even if it could be done?

Comment: You might want to use [Tensorflow distributions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/Poisson)

Answer (score 1):

Keras has a built-in [Poisson loss function](https://keras.io/losses/)! If you have multiple outcomes, Keras will just apply the loss function to predictions for each variable, and sum them (you'd have to create a custom loss function if you want to weigh the loss for one variable more than for another).

As an aside, you don't need to worry about calculating the factorial in the PMF in order to maximize the likelihood, since `factorial(y_true[i])` isn't a function of the model parameters. There's a quick derivation of the objective function (loss function is just the negative of this) on the [Poisson Regression wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#Maximum_likelihood-based_parameter_estimation). It's in the context of a linear model, but just replace `theta_prime * x[i]` with `y_pred[i]` and it matches the context here.